# How do I check input data from edits that will be posted to a database with delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ado

I have written a database Application With Delphi7. Im using the ADODatabase.  I am using edits to get input from the user but the program doesnt work, it checks the input data but never posts it. I have three tables name Clients Receivers and Packages, please help me. Here is the code:

```
 'procedure TNewDel.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  Var
 Name, Name2,LName,LName2, SMessage,Date, Date2, ClNum,PackNum, RcNum, email, email2,  address, address2, cell, Cell2, Cellnum, Cellnum2, Price  :string;
k, c, c2,CountNum, weight, Distance, size :integer;
rPrice:real;
cCheck:char;
begin

            Date:= FloatToStr(DateTP.Date);
            CountNum:= 0;
            CountNum:=CountNum + 1;
    Name:= edtName.text;
    LName:= edtLName.text;
    SMessage:= ' Wrong input: ';
    Address:= edtAdd.Text;
    Email:= edtEmail.Text;
    cell:= edtCellnum.Text;

    Name2:=edtName2.text;                                     
    LNAme2:=edtLName.text;
    CellNum2:=edtCellNum.text;
    Address2:= edtAdd2.text;
    email2:= edtemail2.text;
    Cell2:= edtCellNum2.text;

    Weight:=sedWeight.value;
    Distance:= sedDist.value;
    Size:= sedSize.Value;



For K := 1 to 4       do                                                                              
 Begin
  Date2:= Date2+date[k];
 End;

 If LName= '' then  
      Begin                                                                       
         ShowMessage(sMessage+ 'Last Name');
        End
 Else


 Begin
If Name= '' then
    begin
         ShowMessage(sMessage+ 'Name');
    End

Else


    Begin
If Address= '' then
    Begin
         ShowMessage(sMessage+ 'Address');
    End

Else
 Begin
If Email= '' then
    Begin
     ShowMessage(sMessage+ 'E-Mail');
End

 Else
    begin   

If Cell = '' then
     Begin
      ShowMessage(sMessage+ 'Cell Phone Number');
            End

    Else    

 Begin

If Cell2 = '' then
    Begin
     Showmessage(sMessage + 'Receiver Cell Number');
        End

Else
 Begin      
 If Name2 = '' then
    Begin
     Showmessage(sMessage + 'Receiver Name');
    End

Else
 Begin      

If LName2 = '' then
    Begin
     Showmessage(sMessage + 'Receiver Last Name');
    End 

Else
 Begin      

If Address2 = '' then
    BEGIN
     Showmessage(sMessage + 'Receiver Address');
    End

Else
Begin       

If Email2 = '' then
    Begin
     Showmessage(sMessage + 'Receiver Cell Number');
    End

Else
 Begin  


If Distance='' then
    Begin
     ShowMessage(sMessage+ 'Distance');
    End

Else
 Begin      
If Size='' then
    begin 
     ShowMessage(sMessage+ 'Size');
    End

Else
Begin       

If Weight > 35 Then


Begin
   Showmessage('Package too heavy');
end
  Else

        Begin
    If Distance <= 150 then
        begin
         rPrice:= Distance*3.5;
         Price:= FloatToStr(rPrice);
        End

               Else
    Begin
        If distance >150 then
            Begin
             rPrice:= (150*3.5)+((distance-150)*3.5*2);
             Price:=FloatToStr(rPrice);
            End

    Else
Begin 
    If distance = 0 then
    Begin
    ShowMessage(sMessage + 'Distance');
    END

Else
Begin
CCheck:= 't';
end;
 End;


If CCheck = 't' then
Begin
        For c:= 2 to 10 do
                    Begin
                       CellNum:= Cellnum+ Cell[c];
                      End;
                        CellNum:= '+27' + Cellnum;
        For c2:= 2 to 10 do
            Begin
             CellNum2:= Cellnum2 +Cell2[c2];
            end;
     CellNum2:= '+27' + CellNum2 ;

ClNum:= 'CL'+ Name[1]+LName[1]  + Date2 + IntToStr(CountNum);
PackNum:='PK' + Name[1]+Name2[1]+ Date2;
RcNum:= 'RC'+ Name2[1]+Lname2[1]+ Date2;


ADOTable1.edit;
  ADOtable1Package_Number.Value:= PackNum;
  ADOTable1client_Number.Value:=ClNum;
  ADOTable1Name:=Name;
  ADOTable1Last_Name.Value:= LName;
  ADOTable1Address.Value:=Address;
  ADOTable1e_mail.Value:=email;
  ADOTable1Cell_Number.Value:=CellNUm;
  ADOTable1Date.Value:=Date;
Post;
End;

With ADOTable2 do
Begin
 Insert;
  FieldByName('Package_Number').Value:= PackNum;
  FieldByName('Receiver_Number').Value:=RCNum;
  FieldByName('Name').Value:=Name2;
  FieldByName('Last_Name').Value:=LNAme2;
  FieldByName('Address').Value:=Address2;
  FieldByName('E_mail').Value:=email2;
  FieldByName('Date').Value:=Date;
Post;
End;


with ADOTable3 do
    begin
     Insert;
      FieldByname('Price').Value:= Price;
      FieldByName('Package_Number').Value:= PackNum;
      FieldByName('Client_Number').Value:= ClNum;
      FieldByName('Receiver_Number').Value:=RcNum;
  FieldByName('Weight').Value:= Weight;
  FieldByName('Size').Value:=Size;
  FieldByName('Price').Value:= Price;
  FieldByName('Distance').Value:= Distance;
Post;
    end;

end;

end;
end;
 end;
 end;
  end;
end;
  end;
    end;
      end;
        end;
          end;
            end;
              end;
                end;
                  end;
```

I know it might not be the best way to do so, i am a biggener so thats why i am asking. Thanks.

Comment: this almost infinite nested `IF` is impossible to read. Generally you should refactor such a code bomb into small procedures. Hopefully this would come with more experience.
However for starters please rework that procedure into the small non-nested sequence as one of those two patterns: http://pastebin.com/8AGGkidw - currently not only you can hardly parse it, but it is hard for anyone else as well.
PS: just a suggestion to novice to get answers faster: catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: If you indent your code proper, you will see, that if you enter `If Distance <= 150 then` you will never enter the ELSE Part with the posts.

Comment: @Bummi you're  monster :-D But why not making am answer then ? PS. But best indentation in this case - no indentation (and no nesting) at all.  PS. to topic starter - do avoid names like "Button1" - give it a reasonable name. Just in the month you would not be able to understand the difference between `Button1Click` and `Button2Click` without long and tedious reading. Don't start this bad habbit - it is a time-consuming brain-eating swamp.

Comment: Is there any good reason to avoid using dataware components? They would make good part of the code go away.

Comment: @AlexSC maybe he does not want error displayed in the middle of editing and only before posting. Though visual validators marking components could be used

Comment: The questions seems extremly broad to me, depending on the existing knowledge and Database, many solutions would be possible. From using views with `Instead of triggers` and calculated fields over `OnValidate` or `BeforePost` events, using own validation classes,  down to using stored procedures with collection possibe problems to a list for raising an error before executing. Using `data aware controls` with the given validation events would in any case reduce code or at least make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like

```
function CheckValues(const aValue, aConst: Array of string): string;
var
  a_Index: integer;
  a_Const: String;
begin
  Result := '';
  Assert(High(aValue)= High(aConst), 'Programmer Error CheckValues: Value and Const should have the same amount of elements');
  for a_Index := Low(aValue) to High(aValue) do
  begin
    if (aValue[a_Index] = '') then
    begin
      a_Const := aConst[a_Index];
      if Result = '' then
        Result := a_Const
      else
        Result := Result + ', ' +  a_Const;
    end;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm.AllowSave;
var
  a_Value: string;
begin
  if FInit then
  begin
    a_Value := CheckValues([cbChain.Text, edName.Text, edTaxId.Text, edCustomerNo.Text, ReversalWindow.Text, editAddress1.Text,
    editCity.Text, cbState.Text, editZip.Text, editPhone.Text, editFax.Text, editEmail.Text, cbPricingTypeLU.Text],
   ['Chain','Name',  'Tax Id', 'Customer Number', 'Reversal Window', 'Address1',
    'City', 'State', 'Zip', 'Phone', 'Fax', 'Email','Pricing Type']);


    btnSave.Enabled := a_Value = '';
    if btnSave.Enabled then
    begin
      StatusBar1.SimpleText := '';
      if not (qryEdit.State in [dsInsert, dsEdit]) then
        qryEdit.Edit;
    end else
      StatusBar1.SimpleText := 'Missing: ' + a_Value;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Few tips for database application coding (considering you as a beginner):

1. It is always better to use DB aware controls. (Example: use TDBEdit instead of TEdit)
2. For data validation use event handlers.

As in your case you can do this:

1. Use DB aware controls.
2. Handel the OnBeforePost event of all the TADOTable instances

   `procedure TForm1.ADOTable1BeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);`

   `begin`

   `if SameText(ADOTable1Last_Name.AsString, EmptyStr) then`

   `begin`

   ```
    Showmessage(sMessage + 'Receiver Last Name');

    Abort;//here you can also set the focus back to the ADOTable1Last_Name control.
   ```

   `end;`

   `end;`

Gradually you can add all the validations. By doing this you will never need to change your validation code if further you do any changes in your controls. Hope this helps.